# how to get decoded data of jn5148 using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, decode, wireshark, hyperterminal

I am a newbie .  we are using  NXP 's jn518 ek 010  and I am using jennet stack . 
 we are using win 7 and for application development we are using eclipse . 
our project task is to get the temperature , humidity and luminosity sensors value on PC , from which decision making will be proceeded. 
can any one guide me how to get these values in human readable format?
 I have read about the custom flash programmer  which provide these functionality but they were limited to jn5139.
2 )Is it can be done by the help of wireshark?
3 ) can I get values with the help of hyper terminal?

Thanks in advance.